# interact with different language pages in vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm building a multi language website using Laravel and VueJS. I've build many vue components and laravel blade files in same html structure and those are different languages. I suppose to make different route file to each language.

But my problem is I cannot switch between different language. Please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using blade and Vue as a library you can use https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

If you're using Vue as SPA you can use https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

Comment: I haven't clear idea about whether i'm using blade or SPA. Can you give me some ideas about those things please?